# OpenGL ES:Purpose of calling glClear on every frame

Tags: opengl-es

I'am new to OpenGL ES and I try to draw triangle,but I can't understand what is a purpose of calling glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) on every frame?Without it some strange artifacts occur on screen.Should I call this every time at every frame beginning?
Thanks

Comment: Finish a game of solitaire, you will see the effect of not clearing the color buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified: If you draw a triangle, only the part of the framebuffer that actually *contains* the triangle is being redrawn. So if you draw it once, then shift it a little bit and draw it again in the next frame, without a call to glClear, the contents of the previous frame will still be present in the framebuffer.

That's the cause of your artifacts and the reason why you should `glClear` your framebuffer every time you suspect something has *changed* in the image displayed. For most applications, this would indeed mean: Every frame.

Comment: Thank for your answer,you said that "So if you draw it once, then shift it a little bit and draw it again in the next frame",I don't shift it,but if I look at artifacts I see that triangles are overlapped with some shift,but how this shift occur?

Comment: @user2187460: This may be an artifact of multisamples FSAA, which may be enabled on your system. Also you might experience some kind of Z fighting.