# Is calling gl clear necessary?

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es

I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506110/opengl-espurpose-of-calling-glclear-on-every-frame) while searching for an answer. In my case I'm drawing an entire filled rectangular screen. So seeing that there will be no leftover pixels for drawing, will omitting GLclear in this very specific scenario increase performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glClear.xhtml) is not necessary (provided you don't use a [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test), [Stencil test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Stencil_Test) or [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)). `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` just sets the color of each fragment in the framebuffer. If you write into each fragment during the rendering,  there is no need for `glClear`.
The relative performance gain depends on the complexity of your scene and the render pipeline. Most likely, it's not that big, but there will be an effect.